# Android NDK: Issues with variable

Tags: c, android-ndk

I am porting an application, the existing MakeFile has the following...

```
ETC_GITATTRIBUTES = $(sysconfdir)/gitattributes
ETC_GITATTRIBUTES_SQ = $(subst ','\'',$(ETC_GITATTRIBUTES))
EXTRA_CPPFLAGS = \
    -DETC_GITATTRIBUTES='"$(ETC_GITATTRIBUTES_SQ)"'
```

So I tried recreating it with...

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNO_GETTEXT -DSHA1_HEADER="openssl/sha.h" -DETC_GITATTRIBUTES=/scard/.app
```

The code both of these are calling is...

```
system_wide = system_path(ETC_GITATTRIBUTES)
```

But the second one gives me the following error...

```
./src/attr.c:476:30: error: expected expression before '/' token
```

If I hardcode like this...

```
system_wide = system_path("/sdcard/.app");
```

This works fine. How do I properly declare my variable in the Android.mk?

**Update**

I also tried this...

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNO_GETTEXT -DSHA1_HEADER="openssl/sha.h" -DETC_GITATTRIBUTES="/scard/.app"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer was "close" but you needed to escape the quotes apparently...

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DNO_GETTEXT -DSHA1_HEADER="openssl/sha.h" -DETC_GITATTRIBUTES=\"/scard/.app\"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code after the C-Preprocessor is done looks like this:

```
system_wide = system_path(/scard/.app)
```

This is because `ETC_GITATTRIBUTES` is literally replaced by `/scard/.ap`.  So you'd need to do:

```
-DETC_GITATTRIBUTES="/scard/.app"
```